# Prove that if $n$ is an integer relatively prime to 72, then $n^6 \equiv 1 $(mod$72$).

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the book, the problem is prove that if $n$ is an integer relatively prime to 72, then $n^{12} \equiv 1 $ (mod$72$), but my professor asked us to show it for $n^6 \equiv 1 $ (mod$72$).

I'm wondering if this is even possible. We are working with Fermat's and Euler's Theorems.  He gave a hint that $72=8\cdot 9.$ So we break it into two parts. For (mod 9) it follows from Euler's Theorem since $\phi(9)=6$, that $n^6 \equiv 1$ (mod 9). But for (mod 8) you get $\phi(8)=4$ so $n^4 \equiv 1$ (mod 8).  How do I get to $n^6 \equiv 1 $ (mod 8)?

Comment: $72 = 8 \times 7$??

Comment: $\phi(8) = 4$ means that $n^4\equiv 1 \mod 8$ but that doesn't mean $4$ is the *lowest* power that that is equvialent to $1$.  If both $n^4 \equiv n^6 \equiv 1$ would mean $n^2\equiv \mod 1$.  So... for $\gcd(n,8) =1$ *does* $n^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$?  It's very easy to verify that, yes, they all do.

Comment: ... because $(\pm 1)^2 \equiv 1\mod 8$ and $(\pm 3)^2 \equiv 9\equiv 1 \mod 8$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lambda(72) = \operatorname{lcm}(\lambda(8), \lambda(9)) = \operatorname{lcm}\left(\frac12\varphi(8),\varphi(9)\right) = \operatorname{lcm}(2,6) = 6$$

where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) and $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Comment: This follows from $U(72) \cong U(8) \times U(9) \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_6$.

Comment: @lhf what does U represent here??

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra, $U(m)$ is the group of units mod $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, there's the chinese remainder theorem.

$72 = 8*9$

$\gcd(n,72)\implies n\equiv \pm 1; \pm 3\mod 8\implies n^2 \equiv 1\mod 8 \implies n^6 \equiv 1 \mod 8$.

$\gcd(n,72)\implies n\equiv \pm 1 \mod 3\implies n^2 \equiv 1\mod 3 \implies n^2 \equiv 1,4,-2 \mod 9 \implies n^6 \equiv 1, 64, -8\equiv 1 \mod 9$
CRT says there is one unique equivilence class $\mod 72$ whare $n^6 \equiv 1 \mod 9$ and $n^6 \equiv 1 \mod 8$.

And that solution is clearly $n^6 \equiv 1 \mod 72$.

Answer (score 0):

$n=1$ is easy, and you could try $n=3$.

$5^6 \equiv (-3)^6 \equiv 3^6 \mod 8$ and similarly
$7^6 \equiv (-1)^6 \equiv 1^6 \mod 8$.

Answer (score 0):

The Euler totient function of $72$ is $24$ so $(n^6)^4\equiv 1 \bmod 72$.  But, which fourth roots of unity are available for $n^6$?  We must choose between $+1$ and $-1$ because no square roots of $-1$ exist when the modulus has a $4n-1$ prime factor.  And $n^6\equiv -1$ implies a square that is one less than a multiple of $4$, oops.  $n^6\equiv +1 \bmod 72$ is all we have left.

Answer (score 0):

$$ n^6-1 = (n-1)(n+1)(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n+1) $$
and if $n$ is odd, $(n-1)(n+1)$ is a multiple of $8$. If $n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ we have that both $(n-1)$ and $(n^2+n+1)$ are multiples of $3$. If $n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ we have that both $(n+1)$ and $(n^2-n+1)$ are multiples of $3$. It follows that:

$$ 2\nmid n, 3\nmid n\quad\Longrightarrow\quad 72\mid(n^6-1).$$